# Vue lazy-loading components

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, lazy-loading

I wanted to try to lazy-load a module in my custom vue application, but I ran into an issue.

Basically, I have my routes set up from database, and one of them is the route to display programs (for children). In this program, I load several components, like list of clients, consents, etc.

Currently, I have it like so:

```
   <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" :class="{'active': current_tab == 'consent'}" id="consent" v-if="displayConsentComponent">
    <consent v-model="consents" :edit="edit"></consent>
</div>

// and they are imported like so:

<script>
    import Consent                  from './_consents';
    import AssignedStaff            from './_assigned-staff';
        ......
    export default {
        components:{
            Consent,
            AssignedStaff,
            .....
        },
        data(){
            return {
                  ..........
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

but wanted to adapt it like you did, so I changed it to this:

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" :class="{'active': current_tab == 'consent'}" id="consent" v-if="displayConsentComponent">
    <consent v-model="consents" :edit="edit"></consent>
</div>

// and they are imported like so:

<script>
    const Consent       = () => import('./_consents');
    const AssignedStaff = () => import('./_assigned-staff');
        ......
    export default {
        components:{
            Consent,
            AssignedStaff,
            .....
        },
        data(){
            return {
                  ..........
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

but unfortunately my whole application fails to build and run (if I rebuild it), or get this error otherwise:

```
in ./~/babel-loader/lib!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/programs/program.vue Module parse failed: E:\Gabi\khcc-crm-playground\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js!E:\Gabi\khcc-crm-playground\node_modules\vue-loader\lib\selector.js?type=script&index=0!E:\Gabi\khcc-crm-playground\src\components\programs\program.vue

Unexpected token (58:8) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type. SyntaxError: Unexpected token (58:8) at Parser.pp$4.raise (E:\Gabi\khcc-crm-playground\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15) at Parser.pp.unexpected (E:\Gabi\khcc-crm-playground\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:603:10) at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (E:\Gabi\khcc-crm-playground\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1822:12) at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (E:\Gabi\khcc-crm-playground\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1715:21) at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (E:\Gabi\khcc-crm-playground\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19) at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (E:\Gabi\khcc-crm-playground\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21) at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (E:\Gabi\khcc-crm-playground\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21) at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (E:\Gabi\khcc-crm-playground\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:21) at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (E:\Gabi\khcc-crm-playground\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1573:21) at Parser.pp$1.parseReturnStatement (E:\Gabi\khcc-crm-playground\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:839:33) at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (E:\Gabi\khcc-crm-playground\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:699:34) at Parser.pp$1.parseBlock (E:\Gabi\khcc-crm-playground\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:981:25) at Parser.pp$3.parseFunctionBody (E:\Gabi\khcc-crm-playground\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2105:24) at Parser.pp$1.parseFunction (E:\Gabi\khcc-crm-playground\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1065:10) at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (E:\Gabi\khcc-crm-playground\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1810:19) at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (E:\Gabi\khcc-crm-playground\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1715:21) @ ./src/components/programs/program.vue 3:2-107
```

I have updated my node packages, including vue to the latest version (2.5.1X, if I remember correctly), but to no avail. Can somebody help me out with some thoughts?

Much appreciated,
Gabriel

Comment: check https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to move the async component to `components`.
You can visit here for reading more:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components

```
<script>

    export default {
        components:{
            Consent: () => import('./_consents'),
            AssignedStaff: () => import('./_assigned-staff'),
            .....
        },
        data(){
            return {
                  ..........
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```